# Is it possible to get MarvinSketch to number the atoms in your molecule and if so how?

Tags: chemaxon

I'd like to be able to create a table displaying different substituents and bonds inside the different members of drug groups like the morphinan opioids and as part of that it would be great if I could create a atom-numbered diagram of morphinan to refer to in said table. I'd just like to know if it is possible to do this in MarvinSketch and, if so, how. I am using MarvinSketch 5.12.3 if it is relevant.

EDIT: I would like MarvinSketch to automatically number each atom. That is, I would like each atom to be assigned the number it is given when naming in IUPAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the manual mapping function (mouseover + <kbd>m</kbd> and the number you wish to add to the atom) to reorder the default atom numbering. There is more information about using the manual mapping function in Marvin [here](https://www.chemaxon.com/forum/ftopic6549.html).

Comment: Um, sorry I wasn't as specific as I had originally thought, please refer to my latest edit (after "EDIT:").

Comment: There is an [IUPAC module](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC-module.html) in biopython. A Python scripting question would be a topic for Stackoverflow.